# Which is the best way to connect to a database with password?

Tags: javascript, sql, security, electron

I'm coding a program with electonjs and I want to connect to a database (as in example).
The problem is that all the queries and the database password can be seen on the files. There must be a way to avoid that, otherwise desktop applications would be very unsecure. What can I do to avoid this? How do the big companies avoid this?

Can anyone suggest (with as many examples as possible) how to avoid this?

Thank you

Example:

```
var config = {
    user: 'sa', 
    password: 'P@$$w0rd',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'WideWorldImporters'
};
```

Comment: I would think that normally you would expose an API with some sort of authentication that connects to the database, instead of connecting directly.

Comment: Google FireBase may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There must be a way to avoid that

No, there isn't.  Even if you obfuscate, it can still be undone.  Besides, it's trivial to intercept the password by replacing the server anyway.

> otherwise desktop applications would be very unsecure.

What makes you say that?  If you're accessing your own data, there's nothing insecure about it.

> How do the big companies avoid this?

They don't.  If you can provide an example that you have in mind, we could probably explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a backend if the application is intended for multiple users. If you need a database only for offline purposes, you can use something like sqlite.

Also see [What should I use as backend in electron application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269937/what-should-i-use-as-backend-in-electron-application)